# php redis expire does not accept mode

Tags: php, redis

[Docs](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis#expire-pexpire) for php redis say that you can use MODE option when setting expiration of a key:

```
public function expire(string $key, int $seconds, ?string $mode = NULL): Redis|bool;

public function pexpire(string $key, int $milliseconds, ?string $mode = NULL): Redis|bool;
```

When I do:

```
$redis->expire($key,10,"NX");
```

I get na error:

```
Uncaught ErrorException: Redis::expire() expects exactly 2 parameters, 3 given
```

What am I doing wrong?

// php 7.4.33, output from $redis->info();

```
{
    "redis_version": "7.2.3",
    "redis_git_sha1": 0,
    "redis_git_dirty": 0,
    "redis_build_id": "b7a5a890a49538f3",
    "redis_mode": "standalone",
    "os": "Linux 3.10.0-1160.53.1.el7.x86_64 x86_64",
    "arch_bits": 64,
    "monotonic_clock": "POSIX clock_gettime",
    "multiplexing_api": "epoll",
    "atomicvar_api": "c11-builtin",
    "gcc_version": "8.3.1",
    "process_id": 3542,
    "process_supervised": "systemd",
    "run_id": "5620ae96fcd3f159f90a3cdb457c8fb0567a7542",
    "tcp_port": 6379,
    "server_time_usec": 1700163866639392,
    "uptime_in_seconds": 425,
    "uptime_in_days": 0,
    "hz": 10,
    "configured_hz": 10,
    "lru_clock": 5665050,
    "executable": "/usr/bin/redis-server",
    "config_file": "/etc/redis/redis.conf",
    "io_threads_active": 0,
    "listener0": "name=tcp,bind=127.0.0.1,port=6379",
    "connected_clients": 1,
    "cluster_connections": 0,
    "maxclients": 10000,
    "client_recent_max_input_buffer": 0,
    "client_recent_max_output_buffer": 0,
    "blocked_clients": 0,
    "tracking_clients": 0,
    "clients_in_timeout_table": 0,
    "total_blocking_keys": 0,
    "total_blocking_keys_on_nokey": 0,
    "used_memory": 1108120,
    "used_memory_human": "1.06M",
    "used_memory_rss": 6668288,
    "used_memory_rss_human": "6.36M",
    "used_memory_peak": 1131376,
    "used_memory_peak_human": "1.08M",
    "used_memory_peak_perc": "97.94%",
    "used_memory_overhead": 889872,
    "used_memory_startup": 867776,
    "used_memory_dataset": 218248,
    "used_memory_dataset_perc": "90.81%",
    "allocator_allocated": 1194888,
    "allocator_active": 1478656,
    "allocator_resident": 5160960,
    "total_system_memory": 33422483456,
    "total_system_memory_human": "31.13G",
    "used_memory_lua": 31744,
    "used_memory_vm_eval": 31744,
    "used_memory_lua_human": "31.00K",
    "used_memory_scripts_eval": 0,
    "number_of_cached_scripts": 0,
    "number_of_functions": 0,
    "number_of_libraries": 0,
    "used_memory_vm_functions": 32768,
    "used_memory_vm_total": 64512,
    "used_memory_vm_total_human": "63.00K",
    "used_memory_functions": 184,
    "used_memory_scripts": 184,
    "used_memory_scripts_human": "184B",
    "maxmemory": 0,
    "maxmemory_human": "0B",
    "maxmemory_policy": "noeviction",
    "allocator_frag_ratio": 1.24,
    "allocator_frag_bytes": 283768,
    "allocator_rss_ratio": 3.49,
    "allocator_rss_bytes": 3682304,
    "rss_overhead_ratio": 1.29,
    "rss_overhead_bytes": 1507328,
    "mem_fragmentation_ratio": 6.24,
    "mem_fragmentation_bytes": 5600176,
    "mem_not_counted_for_evict": 0,
    "mem_replication_backlog": 0,
    "mem_total_replication_buffers": 0,
    "mem_clients_slaves": 0,
    "mem_clients_normal": 0,
    "mem_cluster_links": 0,
    "mem_aof_buffer": 0,
    "mem_allocator": "jemalloc-5.3.0",
    "active_defrag_running": 0,
    "lazyfree_pending_objects": 0,
    "lazyfreed_objects": 0,
    "loading": 0,
    "async_loading": 0,
    "current_cow_peak": 0,
    "current_cow_size": 0,
    "current_cow_size_age": 0,
    "current_fork_perc": 0,
    "current_save_keys_processed": 0,
    "current_save_keys_total": 0,
    "rdb_changes_since_last_save": 21,
    "rdb_bgsave_in_progress": 0,
    "rdb_last_save_time": 1700163742,
    "rdb_last_bgsave_status": "ok",
    "rdb_last_bgsave_time_sec": 0,
    "rdb_current_bgsave_time_sec": -1,
    "rdb_saves": 1,
    "rdb_last_cow_size": 491520,
    "rdb_last_load_keys_expired": 0,
    "rdb_last_load_keys_loaded": 410,
    "aof_enabled": 0,
    "aof_rewrite_in_progress": 0,
    "aof_rewrite_scheduled": 0,
    "aof_last_rewrite_time_sec": -1,
    "aof_current_rewrite_time_sec": -1,
    "aof_last_bgrewrite_status": "ok",
    "aof_rewrites": 0,
    "aof_rewrites_consecutive_failures": 0,
    "aof_last_write_status": "ok",
    "aof_last_cow_size": 0,
    "module_fork_in_progress": 0,
    "module_fork_last_cow_size": 0,
    "total_connections_received": 317,
    "total_commands_processed": 929,
    "instantaneous_ops_per_sec": 0,
    "total_net_input_bytes": 35138,
    "total_net_output_bytes": 26395,
    "total_net_repl_input_bytes": 0,
    "total_net_repl_output_bytes": 0,
    "instantaneous_input_kbps": 0,
    "instantaneous_output_kbps": 0,
    "instantaneous_input_repl_kbps": 0,
    "instantaneous_output_repl_kbps": 0,
    "rejected_connections": 0,
    "sync_full": 0,
    "sync_partial_ok": 0,
    "sync_partial_err": 0,
    "expired_keys": 0,
    "expired_stale_perc": 0,
    "expired_time_cap_reached_count": 0,
    "expire_cycle_cpu_milliseconds": 4,
    "evicted_keys": 0,
    "evicted_clients": 0,
    "total_eviction_exceeded_time": 0,
    "current_eviction_exceeded_time": 0,
    "keyspace_hits": 566,
    "keyspace_misses": 54,
    "pubsub_channels": 0,
    "pubsub_patterns": 0,
    "pubsubshard_channels": 0,
    "latest_fork_usec": 226,
    "total_forks": 1,
    "migrate_cached_sockets": 0,
    "slave_expires_tracked_keys": 0,
    "active_defrag_hits": 0,
    "active_defrag_misses": 0,
    "active_defrag_key_hits": 0,
    "active_defrag_key_misses": 0,
    "total_active_defrag_time": 0,
    "current_active_defrag_time": 0,
    "tracking_total_keys": 0,
    "tracking_total_items": 0,
    "tracking_total_prefixes": 0,
    "unexpected_error_replies": 0,
    "total_error_replies": 0,
    "dump_payload_sanitizations": 0,
    "total_reads_processed": 1246,
    "total_writes_processed": 929,
    "io_threaded_reads_processed": 0,
    "io_threaded_writes_processed": 0,
    "reply_buffer_shrinks": 72,
    "reply_buffer_expands": 0,
    "eventloop_cycles": 5784,
    "eventloop_duration_sum": 582295,
    "eventloop_duration_cmd_sum": 1494,
    "instantaneous_eventloop_cycles_per_sec": 9,
    "instantaneous_eventloop_duration_usec": 155,
    "acl_access_denied_auth": 0,
    "acl_access_denied_cmd": 0,
    "acl_access_denied_key": 0,
    "acl_access_denied_channel": 0,
    "role": "master",
    "connected_slaves": 0,
    "master_failover_state": "no-failover",
    "master_replid": "d67bcdda1b07cd143a6eac43a9169de0053a419e",
    "master_replid2": 0,
    "master_repl_offset": 0,
    "second_repl_offset": -1,
    "repl_backlog_active": 0,
    "repl_backlog_size": 1048576,
    "repl_backlog_first_byte_offset": 0,
    "repl_backlog_histlen": 0,
    "used_cpu_sys": 0.271825,
    "used_cpu_user": 0.447708,
    "used_cpu_sys_children": 0.002234,
    "used_cpu_user_children": 0,
    "used_cpu_sys_main_thread": 0.269767,
    "used_cpu_user_main_thread": 0.448196,
    "cluster_enabled": 0,
    "db0": "keys=103,expires=0,avg_ttl=0",
    "db1": "keys=1,expires=0,avg_ttl=0",
    "db2": "keys=310,expires=0,avg_ttl=0",
    "db3": "keys=1,expires=0,avg_ttl=0"
}
```